# Ping value in java

Tags: java, ip, return-value, ping

I know that this question has been approached under different ways, but I have checked stackoverflow and I didn't found the answer I was looking for.

To make it simple : Is there a way to get the **Time ping value** to an IP server under *Windows* ?

I know how to check if some servers are reachable, but I would like to have precise values, like we can read on terminal.

**Thank you** for your help and understanding.

Comment: what "value" are you looking for? a ping returns many values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
//The command to execute
String pingCmd = "ping " + ip + " -t";

//get the runtime to execute the command
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(pingCmd);     

//Gets the inputstream to read the output of the command
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

//reads the outputs
String inputLine = in.readLine();
while ((inputLine != null)) {
    if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
       ........
    }
    inputLine = in.readLine();
}
```

[reference](http://wikijava.org/wiki/Execute_external_program_%28ping_and_complain%29)

**UPDATE:**  As per your need

```
public class PingDemo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ip = "localhost";
        String time = "";

        //The command to execute
        String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;

        //get the runtime to execute the command
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process process = runtime.exec(pingCmd);

            //Gets the inputstream to read the output of the command
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            //reads the outputs
            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine != null)) {
                if (inputLine.length() > 0 && inputLine.contains("time")) {
                     time = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("time"));
                     break;                        
                }
                inputLine = in.readLine();
            }    
            System.out.println("time --> " + time);    
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Written in little haste.

Comment: Also in your first answer in: 
String pingCmd = "ping " + ip + " -t"
it should be "ping -t " + number + ip

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the **ping** command and read the output (as explained in the previous answer), or if you need a lower lever access (like you can do with RAW sockets), you can have a look at the **jpcap** java library.

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12077703/1329572), you'll want to make use of the `Runtime` class to shell out a ping. All that's required of you is to parse the input stream (possibly using regex to get the time ping value).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the host to be pinged : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
    String str = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the no. of packets to be sent : ");
    int packets = sc.nextByte();
    String pingResult;
    int count=0;
    try{
        String command = "ping -c "+ packets +" -w 10 " + str;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(count==packets+4) {
                pingResult = (inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("=")));
                pingResult = (pingResult.substring
                        (pingResult.indexOf("/")+1,pingResult.indexOf("/")+7));
                System.out.println(pingResult + " ms");
            }
            count++;
        }
        in.close();
        if(count==0)System.out.println("Wrong host entered.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Output:
Enter the host to be pinged : 
8.8.8.8
Enter the no. of packets to be sent : 
5
31.406 ms

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is to find average time to ping a host.